# What historic examples are there of swords being used a primary weapon in history?

Tags: warfare, sword

Before anybody says anything I've already heard it all before
"Swords were historically sidearms."
"Swords aren't meant to be primary weapons."
and all other such things.

I honestly couldn't tell you if these circles tend to be particularly Eurocentric or if I'm just a dingo for favoring possibility over historical precedent.
But regardless, I really want examples of swords being used as the primary weapon of a military, or at the very least the possibility of one being chosen as the primary weapon of a hired hand or a mercenary.

I know for the fact the Romans did it for a time with great success in tandem with their large shields, I've seen rapiers rip through chain-mail with middling difficulty and so one could be used with a similar strategy in mind, and then there are Zweihanders that are so big and weighty that they generally did not care about the reach of pole-arms or the durability of most armor.

These are but a few examples and I really want to know if there are anymore, but every time I try to find more answers, I'm just met with the same responses devoid of any imagination that care more about what was then what could be.

So, I thought I'd try my luck here,see if you guys can help me out. Just any example of a weapon or weapon combination that would make a person think "This is my first choice."

Comment: There are some people with swords in [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pulasti_(Philistine)_and_Tsakkaras_(painting).png)

Comment: [And some more](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:UenoSenso.jpg)

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  The people you've been hearing from sound rather uninformed, and probably not worth arguing with.

Comment: @MCW well that one's admittedly my fault, it's what I get for expecting anything out of people who use Reddit on a regular basis.

Comment: The *only* way this makes sense if if we're talking about infantry  (Unless you exclude cavalry sabers), and only in specific engagements.  Both the Chinese and Japanese aristocracy would argue with this statement. Ultimately, I think this is a case of [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) and probably a [category error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this will be the list answer:

- Roman legionaries post [Marian reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marian_reforms).
- Some units in [Landsknecht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsknecht) pike square were armed wit two handed swords in order to break opposing pike formation.

> 300 men of a Fähnlein would be armed with a pike [...] Experienced and
> well-equipped soldiers, receiving double a normal Landsknecht's pay
> and getting the title Doppelsöldner, made up a quarter of each
> Fähnlein. 50 of these men were armed with a halberd or with a [...]
> two-handed sword called a Zweihänder while another fifty were
> arquebusiers or crossbowmen.

- [Hussar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hussar) type of light cavalry starting in the 18th century would be armed almost exclusively with different type of sabers based on period and country. Light cavalry armed with a lance would be called "Lancers" or "Uhlans".

-[Cuirassier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuirassier) type of heavy cavalry as well starting late 17th century.

> Cuirassiers first appeared in mid-to-late 16th century Europe as a
> result of armoured cavalry, such as men-at-arms and demi-lancers
> discarding their lances and adopting pistols as their primary
> weapon. In the later part of the 17th century, the cuirassier lost
> his limb armour and subsequently wore only the cuirass (breastplate
> and backplate), and sometimes a helmet. By this time, the sword or
> sabre had become his primary weapon, with pistols relegated to a
> secondary function.

-[Royal navy enlisted sailors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Navy_cutlasses) in 19th century were issued cutlass for boarding actions.

> In the Royal Navy it was a sword purchased by the
> government and issued to ratings, the enlisted men. Officers carried
> privately purchased long swords and midshipmen dirks. Seaborne
> soldiers of the Royal Marines were not issued cutlasses and instead
> carried bayonets for their longarms. When carrying out a boarding
> action the first wave of sailors would often be issued a cutlass and
> pistol for offensive action while the second wave were armed with more
> defensive weapons such as the boarding pike.

-There is also a late 16th to 17th century fighting system called [Rules of Montante](https://hroarr.com/manuals/iberian/Figueiredo-Diogo-Gomes-de-Montante-Translation-Myers-and-Hick-1651.pdf), with some of its mutations, is specifically designed for bodyguards and fight in urban enviroment.

[- Spanish Rodeleros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodeleros) though some other countries used had their own versions. Were short-lived military unit armed with sword and circular shield in 16th century.

> [Spaniards] used small groups of sword and buckler men to break the deadlock
> of the push of pike, [...]
> comparable to the role of the German Doppelsöldner during the same
> period. [...] however, when facing a fresh, well-ordered
> pike square, they were vulnerable [...] They
> were also very vulnerable to attack by cavalry, while halberdiers were
> not.

Interestingly they were excessively used during the Spanish conquest of Americas

> The majority of Hernán Cortés' troops during his campaigns in the New
> World were rodeleros: in 1520, over 1000 of his 1300 men were so
> equipped, and in 1521 he had 700 rodeleros, but only 118 arquebusiers
> and crossbowm

en.

Comment: I think it's a bit of a stretch to include the RN enlisted sailors in the list. As the 19th Century went on the number of boarding actions greatly decreased. The 'primary weapon' of a sailor of the time was the ship's cannon.

Comment: @SteveBird that's a fair point. This is very specific niche, for very specific situation.

Comment: I think we can also add the spanish roderos on to this list as well.(I just found out about these guys a few hours ago)

Comment: @Masakan Indeed, I knew of them, but couldn't get the name right enough for google to spit some article on them. The correct term is Rodeleros.